# Minimax algorithm doesnt go for mate in chess

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

My goal is to code a somewhat OK chess engine, in the following position it's a mate in 2 which the engine should easily find with its depth of 4-5.

[image: Chess board with FEN: rr2k3/8/8/8/8/8/8/4K3 (black to play)]

The first move the AI makes is Ra2 to trap the white king, the white king goes to f1 and instead of mating the AI moves the Rook to c2.

```
  var initial_depth = depth;
  var bestMove = null;
  var nodes = 0;
  var ret = await minimax(position, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer);
  console.log("nodes visited: " + nodes);
  return ret;
 
  async function minimax(position, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer) {
    nodes++;
    if (maximizingPlayer) {
      var validMoves = await getValidMoves(position, ArrtoFEN(position) + " w");
    } else {
      var validMoves = await getValidMoves(position, ArrtoFEN(position) + " b");
    }
    if (validMoves.length < 1 || depth == 0) {
      var eval = await getEval(position);
      return [eval, null];
    }
 
    if (maximizingPlayer) {
      var maxEval = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
      for (var i = 0; i < validMoves.length; i++) {
        var move = validMoves[i];
        
        var testbrd = makeMove(move, position)  //not the actual code. shortend for Readability
 
        
        var eval = await minimax(testbrd, depth - 1, alpha, beta, false);
        if (eval[0] > maxEval) {
          maxEval = eval[0];
          if (initial_depth == depth) {
            bestMove = move;
            console.log("current bestmove: " + bestMove);
          }
        }
        alpha = Math.max(alpha, eval[0]);
        if (beta <= alpha) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return [maxEval, bestMove];
    } else {
      var minEval = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
 
      for (var i = 0; i < validMoves.length; i++) {
        var move = validMoves[i]; 
          
        var testbrd = makeMove(move, position)//not the actual code. shortend for Readability
 
        var eval = await minimax(testbrd, depth - 1, alpha, beta, true);
        if (eval[0] < minEval) {
          minEval = eval[0];
          if (initial_depth == depth) {
            bestMove = move;
            console.log("current bestmove: " + bestMove);
          }
        }
        beta = Math.min(beta, eval[0]);
        if (beta <= alpha) {
          break;
        }
      }
 
      return [minEval, bestMove];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it sees that any move will win, and you don't have a condition that tells the engine that it is better to do mate in 1 move than in 5 moves. If at the end of a search find that you have 0 legal moves and you are in check, then you are checkmated. In this case you want to send back a checkmate score (large negative value) and add the ply from this. This way you will make it better to mate in fewer moves than in a larger amount of moves.

I suggest you go for Negamax alogirthm in stead of minimax. It will mean much less code and much easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment, I made the Eval function return a value of +-1000 on checkmate and added the depth to that, thus favoring a "fast" checkmate.

Comment: Cool, nice to hear it's working!